C# Creating a Square
I'm trying to create an application that inputs a Width and Height to design a square. I've gotten the error handling for inputting the numbers for the Width and Height. I find myself writing...
//Integer for Width == W
int W;
//Integer for Height == H
int H;
      if (W == 1 && H == 1)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("*");
      }
      else if (W == 1 && H == 2)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("*\n" +
                           "*");
      }
      else if (W == 1 && H == 3)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("*\n" +
                           "*\n" +
                           "*");
      }
     //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      else if (W == 1 && H == 20)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("*\n" +
                           "*\n" +
                          //~~~~~~~
     //For readability 20th"*");


Also, assuming I'd do (else if) another 396 more times to satisfy the variances (20 * 20 = 400) 400 possibilities to build this square.
I'm asking if there is any looping methods that could help me reduce the code I need to complete making my square out of Console.WriteLine("*").
if(W == 1 && H == 1) ~~~ else(W == 20 && H == 20)
Or am I stuck writing the 400 possible instances of the width and height of my square?
The desired result for the display
 ****
 *  *
 *  *
 ****

Thanks for your time and consideration of my question.

Surely there is a way to logically produce the output without hard-coding every possible result.  Have you tried anything?  Start by defining what your expected results are for a small sample of inputs.  What patterns can you observe?  When you attempt to define those patterns logically in code to produce that result, what happens?

Logic would be simple:
write * character as many times as W, then write new line to start new row - repeat this as many times as H
Putting it into code:
var W = 10;
var H = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < H; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < W; j++)
    {
        Console.Write('*');
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Using more concise code:
for (var i = 0; i < H; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', W));
}

UPDATE
In order to draw only border with characters:
var W = 10;
var H = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < H; i++)
{
    // for bottom and for top borders - print full line
    if (i == 0 || i == H - 1)
        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', W));
    // for other, print just W-2 spaces with * at the edges
    else
        Console.WriteLine('*' + new string(' ', W - 2) + '*');
}


Michal, Thank you for your time and speedy answer. That does create a square ''
I need to clarify my question more. Since I'm trying to use the '' or asterisk as a border, a better example of my desired result will be modified to the original post.

@H.Cahill I have updated my answer

It ran and worked with my code. With the addition of the variable "borderChar."
I'm being picky now. Can you do it only with the W and H integers?
W = Int32.Parse(perWidthSquare);
H = Int32.Parse(perLengthSquare);

Since I parsed my W and H from place holder variables?

@H.Cahill see update

You can achieve it via nested loops and a bit of formatting while outputting * to console.
var width = 50;
var height = 50;

for (var x = 0; x < height; x++)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < width; y++)
    {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == (height - 1) || y == (width - 1))
        {
            Console.Write('*');
        }

        if (x > 0 && x < (height - 1) && y > 0 && y < (width - 1))
        {
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

